# Cannot login unless NFS shares are mounted

Tags: mount, login, nfs

I run Ubuntu 18.04 server. I have several NFS shares on a QNAP that is not on 24/7.

New behavior is that if the NFS shares are not up I cannot login at Ubuntu terminal or with WinSCP. I can enter name and password but command prompt does not appear.

If I start the QNAP, then I can login.

Any advice on how I can troubleshoot/correct this?

Comment: Where are the NFS filesystems mounted - on what path'es / mount-point's ?

Comment: Add `nofail` to the options part of each mount in the `/etc/fstab` file so that if they are down the boot will ignore them and move on.

Comment: This is an example line from /etc/fstab: 192.168.1.4:/Multimedia/Movies /mnt/Movies nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,nofail,noauto,x-systemd.automount   0 0 - nofail already in there.

Comment: I can't find all the info for your line(s) there that you are using. I know that intr is deprecated and should not be used. For mine at home with my external NFS mount and my USB drives all I use for the options is `defaults,nofail`. Since I have done that, I have never had a timeout issue during boot if either is down.

Comment: This has fixed it thanks for your help. The /etc/fstab line I quoted is used on another device with a different Debian variant and works fine on that device.